# Why does my COM Smart Pointer get deleted when returning from method

Tags: c++, com

Why does my COM Smart Pointer try to delete when I return from func.  I would think that it's still in scope.  Is there a way to avoid this?

This is the definition in the .TLH file

```
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IComItem, __uuidof(IComItem));
```

```
static IComItemPtr m_pItem;

LPDISPATCH func()
{
    IComItemPtr  pItem = m_pItem;

    pItem = pItem->GetParent();  // Returns parent as IComItemPtr

    return pItem;   // Gets deleted here

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function's return type is a raw `IDispatch*` pointer, not an `IComItemPtr` object (or at least an `IDispatchPtr` object).  The issue you are seeing is due to you incorrectly mixing a smart pointer with a raw pointer.

Since your function does not return a smart wrapper object, a conversion must be performed to convert `pItem` to `IDispatch*`.  [The only conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/803e9tsc.aspx) that `pItem` can perform in this situation is to `IComItem*`, which the compiler can then implicitly convert to `IDispatch*` (since `IComItem` derives from `IDispatch`, otherwise your code wouldn't compile at all).

IOW, your `return` statement is effectively doing this logic:

```
LPDISPATCH func()
{
    IComItemPtr  pItem = m_pItem;

    pItem = pItem->GetParent();  // Returns parent as IComItemPtr

    //return pItem;
    IComItem *pTemp = pItem.operator IComItem*();
    IDispatch *pDisp = (IDispatch*) pTemp;
    return pDisp;

} // <-- pItem is destructed here!
```

No matter what, `pItem` itself is always going to go out of scope when the function exits, decrementing the object's refcount if `pItem` is referencing an object.

So, what is important is that you return a `IDispatch*` pointer to a valid object that has its refcount incremented so the object is not freed when `pItem`'s destructor decrements its refcount.

Try this instead:

```
IComItemPtr func()
{
    return m_pItem->GetParent();  // Returns parent as IComItemPtr
}
```

Or:

```
IDispatchPtr func()
{
    return m_pItem->GetParent();  // Returns parent as IComItemPtr converted to IDispatchPtr
}
```

If you absolutely must return a raw `IDispatch*` pointer, then you have to either:

- manually increment the refcount before exiting:

  ```
  LPDISPATCH func()
  {
      IComItemPtr pItem = m_pItem->GetParent();  // Returns parent as IComItemPtr
      pItem.AddRef();
      return pItem;
  }
  ```
- manually detach the pointer from the wrapper:

  ```
  LPDISPATCH func()
  {
      IComItemPtr pItem = m_pItem->GetParent();  // Returns parent as IComItemPtr
      return pItem.Detach();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You first assumption is incorrect.

```
static IComItemPtr m_pItem;

LPDISPATCH func()
{
    IComItemPtr  pItem = m_pItem;

    pItem = pItem->GetParent();

    return pItem;  // not here.

}   // Gets deleted here (this is where scope is closed).
```

The return will convert `pItem` from `IComItemPtr` to `LPDISPATCH` (`IDispatch*`) before the destructor is then called. The result of this conversion will be placed in the destination.

Note: how the conversion happens will depend entirely on the exact definition of the types involved.